# Not able to send push notifications in ionic getting error:APNS_BAD_DEVICE_TOKEN

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, push-notification

For last two days I am unable to send push notification on Both on Android as well as on iOS. Two days back everything was working fine. But while checking my `uuid`, I am getting blank data array in the response from the url mentioned below

https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications/9ee3e2f9-4226-486b-a01e-ade1559cba1f/messages

response of this url is mentioned below:

> {    "meta": {
>         "status": 200,
>         "request_id": "65683037-3aef-4348-c3ec-b8bd06cca55b",
>         "version": "2.0.0-beta.0"    },    "data": [] }

Comment: Any update on the above problem?

Comment: I'm also having this problem at the moment.